# Table cell line break, and rowcolors

Tags: makecell

This question is about three things:

1. Making forced line break in a cell
2. Combining above with `\rowcolors`
3. Combining above with vertical lines

1.This is obviously a common problem, since I have read several threads about this. But, I have not yet found any real solution to this extremely irritating problem, just trick-fixes.

Basically, I have a table, and in the first column I have a name, a letter and a unit, where I would like the letter and the unit on a second row to save horizontal space. I have tried:

- `p{}` set column width: Doesn't work since the contents are not of
  the same length.
- `\newline` : Which worked ONE time (?) when using
  tabulary, then it stopped working.
- `\parbox` : But I don't want to
  sit and put boxwidth for each cell, that seems completely
  unnecessary.
- `\makecell` and `\thead` : These two works fine and
  allows `\\` inside! They both gives the best line break and cell
  shapes automatically
- `\pbox` : gives similar result as above but
  other alignments.

BUT, now to part 2:

`\makecell` and `\thead` (and `\pbox`) completely messes up `\rowcolors`. It obviously handles the two-line cell as two cells or whatever. SO, how do I solve this problem? Is there another way of inserting line break in a cell or can the `\rowcolors` be manipulated? Can the `\makecell` be manipulated? Haven't found any answer in the CTAN manual for `\makecell` package

3.And further, this is also a known issue. When implementing `\rowcolors`, the colored rows messes up the vertical lines... They are not completely covered, but half covered of halfed in width, which looks like shit. Same crap when using `\rowcolor`. I've tried `\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}` but that only increases width of all lines, not compensating those parts that are messed up. Any wonderful suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{float}

\definecolor{lg}{gray}{0.9}


\begin{document}


\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \rowcolors{1}{lg}{}
    \begin{tabulary}{1\textwidth}{|l|C C C C C|}\hline 
        No. & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
        \makecell[l]{Name} & DIN CK45 & M244 & Alumec 89 & HPFS 7980 & Ti-6Al-4V (Grade 5)\\ 
        \makecell[l]{Type} & HTS & Cast Alu. & Aluminium & Fused Silica & Titanium \\
        \makecell[l]{Young's modulus \\ E [GPa]} & 210 & 90 & 71.5 & 72.7 & 113.8  \\ 
        \makecell[l]{Poisson's ratio \\ $\nu$ [1]} & 0.3 & 0.3 & 0.3 & 0.16 & 0.34 \\ 
        \makecell[l]{Yield strength \\ $\sigma_y$ [MPa]} & 500 & 185 & 550 & - & 880 \\ 
        \makecell[l]{Ultimate strength \\ $\sigma_u$ [MPa]} & 585 & 190 & 590 & 52.4 & 950 \\ 
        \makecell[l]{Reference temp. \\ $t_{ref}$ [\degree C]} & - & 25 & 25 & 25 & - \\ 
        \makecell[l]{Density \\ $\rho$ [kg/m\textsuperscript{3}]} & 7840 & 2650 & 2830 & 2201 & 4430 \\ 
        \makecell[l]{Manufacturer} & Metal Ravne & MAHLE & UDDEHOLM & CORNING & - \\ \hline 
    \end{tabulary}
    \caption{Material data}
    \label{tab:materials1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Almost after one year (!) this answer will not help OP very much ... or maybe I'm wrong :). Anyway, coloring `\makecell` is somehow tricky. Correct coloring you obtain with put `\makecell{...}` into `\cellcolor` macro, for example:

```
 \cellcolor{lg}{\makecell[l]{Poisson's ratio\\ $\nu$ \cite{1}}}
```

However, rather this I rather redesign table into:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=35mm]{geometry}  % <-- added
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}                % <-- added
\usepackage{tabularx}               % <-- changed
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}              % <-- added
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}    % <-- added
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}  % <-- added
\definecolor{lg}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
\centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \rowcolors{1}{lg}{}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| >{\hsize=1.25\hsize}L | *{5}{>{\hsize=0.95\hsize}C} |}
    \hline
\hfil No.   & 1             & 2         & 3         & 4             & 5         \\
    \hline
Name        & DIN CK45      & M244      & Alumec 89 & HPFS 7980     & Ti-6Al-4V (Grade 5)\\
Type        & HTS           & Cast Alu. & Aluminium & Fused Silica  & Titanium  \\
Young's modulus  E [GPa]    
            & 210           & 90        & 71.5      & 72.7          & 113.8     \\
Poisson's ratio $\nu$ \cite{1}
            & 0.3           & 0.3       & 0.3       & 0.16          & 0.34      \\
Yield strength  $\sigma_y$ [MPa] 
            & 500           & 185       & 550       & --            & 880       \\
Ultimate strength $\sigma_u$ [MPa]
            & 585           & 190       & 590       & 52.4          & 950       \\
Reference temp.  $t_{\mathrm{ref}}$ [\si{\degreeCelsius}]
            & --            & 25        & 25        & 25            & --        \\
Density $\rho$ [\si{kg\per\metre\cubed}] & 7840          & 2650      & 2830      & 2201          & 4430      \\
Manufacturer& Metal Ravne   & MAHLE & UDDEHOLM  & CORNING           & --        \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \caption{Material data}
\label{tab:materials1}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{|l|*{5}{X[c]}|}
    \CodeBefore
    \rowcolors[gray]{1}{0.9}{}
    \Body
        \Hline 
        No. & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
        Name & DIN CK45 & M244 & Alumec 89 & HPFS 7980 & Ti-6Al-4V (Grade 5)\\ 
        Type & HTS & Cast Alu. & Aluminium & Fused Silica & Titanium \\
        \Block{}{Young's modulus \\ E [GPa]} & 210 & 90 & 71.5 & 72.7 & 113.8  \\ 
        \Block{}{Poisson's ratio \\ $\nu$ [1]} & 0.3 & 0.3 & 0.3 & 0.16 & 0.34 \\ 
        \Block{}{Yield strength \\ $\sigma_y$ [MPa]} & 500 & 185 & 550 & - & 880 \\ 
        \Block{}{Ultimate strength \\ $\sigma_u$ [MPa]} & 585 & 190 & 590 & 52.4 & 950 \\ 
        \Block{}{Reference temp. \\ $t_{\text{ref}}$ [°C]} & - & 25 & 25 & 25 & - \\ 
        \Block{}{Density \\ $\rho$ [kg/m\textsuperscript{3}]} & 7840 & 2650 & 2830 & 2201 & 4430 \\ 
        Manufacturer & Metal Ravne & MAHLE & UDDEHOLM & CORNING & - \\ 
        \Hline 
    \end{NiceTabular}
    \caption{Material data}
    \label{tab:materials1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how `pbox` messes up row colors for you but it doesn't for me:

```
\newcommand{\multilinebox}[1]{\pbox{\linewidth}{\vspace{.5\b‌​aselineskip}#1\vspac‌​e{.5\baselineskip}}}
```

Comment: Please make complete MWE and show its result. As answer is now, it doesn't work,