# rowcolor doesn't fill complete cell

Tags: tables, tabularx, rowcolor, makecell

So I'm trying to color the rows in my table, but in the rows where I use `\makecell`, the colouring doesn't work properly. Somebody knows a solution for this?

```
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl} %kleurtjes voor table
\definecolor{TopRow}{rgb}{0.4,0.7,1}
\definecolor{NormalRow}{rgb}{0.8,0.9,1}
\usepackage{makecell}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{TopRow}
    \textbf{Peptide Enrichtments} & \textbf{Hits} & \textbf{Found Genes} \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{NormalRow}
    Nothing &3 & \makecell[lt]{RAB5C \\ TNKS1BP1 \\ WDR43}\\
    \hline
    20X dilution& 1 & AHCY \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{NormalRow}
    TiO2& 2 & \makecell[lt]{TNKS1BP1\\ITPR2}\\
    \hline
    TiO2-3 &0& -\\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{NormalRow}
    Fe-NTA & 0&- \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
```

[image: rowcolor doesn't fill whole cell]

EDIT:

So I did the following:

```
Nothing &3 & {\colorbox{NormalRow}{\makecell[lt]{RAB5C \\ TNKS1BP1 \\ WDR43}}}\\
```

But now the alignment is good anymore. anyone has solutions for that?
[image: After using \colorbox the alignment isn't correct anymore]

Comment: Related: [How to color column heads determined width makecell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246889/134144)  and [Table cell line break, and rowcolors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309383/134144). Using `colorbox` around the `makecell` commands should yield the desired result.

Comment: Great, that works. Thank you. However now the words aren't left aligned anymore. Do you have a solution for that as well? Can I define the position of the colorbox?

Comment: You are right. I did not notice the slight shift of the text. In your case, I would suggest, that you drop the usage of  `makecell` completely, as the layout in the table can also be achieved by using three separate rows for the first light blue row. This way you can continue using `rowcolor`.

Comment: An answer that uses \Gape (that works great for me) has also been written here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489251/36302

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to make `makecell` and `colortbl` compatible, I'd suggest dropping the usage of `makecell`. You can achieve the same layout without it as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{TopRow}{rgb}{0.4,0.7,1}
\definecolor{NormalRow}{rgb}{0.8,0.9,1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{TopRow}
    \textbf{Peptide Enrichtments} & \textbf{Hits} & \textbf{Found Genes} \\
  \hline
  \rowcolor{NormalRow}
    Nothing & 3 & RAB5C \\
  \rowcolor{NormalRow}
            &   & TNKS1BP1 \\
  \rowcolor{NormalRow}
            &   & WDR43 \\
  \hline
    20X dilution& 1 & AHCY \\
  \hline
  \rowcolor{NormalRow}
    TiO2 & 2 & TNKS1BP1\\
  \rowcolor{NormalRow}
         &   & ITPR2 \\
  \hline
    TiO2-3 &0& -\\
  \hline
  \rowcolor{NormalRow}
    Fe-NTA & 0&- \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As you use color as a structuring element in your table, you might also consider dropping all the horizonal and vertical rules. In the following example, I have also added a bit of extra vertical space:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{TopRow}{rgb}{0.4,0.7,1}
\definecolor{NormalRow}{rgb}{0.8,0.9,1}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
  \rowcolor{TopRow}
    \textbf{Peptide Enrichtments} & \textbf{Hits} & \textbf{Found Genes} \\
  \rowcolor{NormalRow}
    Nothing & 3 & RAB5C \\
  \rowcolor{NormalRow}
            &   & TNKS1BP1 \\
  \rowcolor{NormalRow}
            &   & WDR43 \\
    20X dilution& 1 & AHCY \\
  \rowcolor{NormalRow}
    TiO2 & 2 & TNKS1BP1\\
  \rowcolor{NormalRow}
         &   & ITPR2 \\
    TiO2-3 &0& -\\
  \rowcolor{NormalRow}
    Fe-NTA & 0&- \\
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

This last example shows a more minimalistic approach without colors and bold text, but with white space and rules from the `booktabs` packages as structural elements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
    Peptide Enrichtments & Hits & Found Genes \\
\midrule
    Nothing      & 3 & RAB5C    \\
                 &   & TNKS1BP1 \\
                 &   & WDR43    \\\addlinespace
    20X dilution & 1 & AHCY     \\\addlinespace
    TiO2         & 2 & TNKS1BP1 \\
                 &   & ITPR2    \\\addlinespace
    TiO2-3       & 0 & -        \\\addlinespace
    Fe-NTA       & 0 & -        \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. That environment provides a command `\rowcolors` (in the so-called `\CodeBefore`) which respect the blocks, created by `\Block`, when the key `respect-blocks` is used.

You will have a perfect output in all the PDF viewers, at all the levels of zoom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|l|l|l|}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor[rgb]{0.4,0.7,1}{1}
  \rowcolors[rgb]{2}{}{0.8,0.9,1}[respect-blocks]
\Body
\Hline
    \textbf{Peptide Enrichtments} & \textbf{Hits} & \textbf{Found Genes} \\
\Hline
    \Block{3-1}{}
    Nothing & 3 & RAB5C \\
            &   & TNKS1BP1 \\
            &   & WDR43 \\
\Hline
    20X dilution& 1 & AHCY \\
\Hline
    \Block{2-1}{}
    TiO2 & 2 & TNKS1BP1\\
         &   & ITPR2 \\
\Hline
    TiO2-3 &0& -\\
\Hline
    Fe-NTA & 0&- \\
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]