# Table coloring doesn't extend all the way with makecell

Tags: tables, color, makecell

This issue occurs while using `xcolor` to alternate the table color, while also using `makecell` to put multiple lines in a table cell. In this specific scenario, where a larger cell is in a colored line, the coloring will stop just before the end of the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}

\rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{white}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ |c|c| } 
    \rowcolor{gray!50}
    \hline
    \textbf{One} & \textbf{Two}\\
    \hline
    Text & More Text\\
    Even More & \makecell{Multiple \\ Lines}\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think `makecell` is a good way to make multi-line cells

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not use `makecell` to do such things.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}

\rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{white}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{2cm}}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12712/156344
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|C|C|} 
    \rowcolor{gray!50}
    \hline
    \textbf{One} & \textbf{Two}\\
    \hline
    Text & More Text\\
    Even More & Multiple Lines\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You could use `\Gape`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}

\rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{white}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ |c|c| } 
    \rowcolor{gray!50}
    \hline
    \textbf{One} & \textbf{Two}\\
    \hline
    Text & More Text\\
    Even More & \Gape[0pt][2pt]{\makecell{Multiple \\ Lines}}\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For completeness. The (relative new) package `tabularray` has own macro for break text in cells into multiline text:

```
{first line\\ second line}
```

Using it at any column width, the row coloring works fine. Also the code is shorter. So, the OP table (extended with two more rows) can be written as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[c,m] Q[c,m]},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries, bg=gray!50},
             row{odd[2]} = {bg=gray!25}
             }
    \toprule
\SetRow{}
One         &   Two                 \\
    \midrule
Text        &   More Text           \\
Even More   & {Multiple\\ Lines}    \\
Text        &   More Text           \\
Even More   & {Multiple\\ Lines}    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr} 
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` has a built-in command `\rowcolors` (which must be used in the so-called `\CodeBefore`).

With that command, you have directly the expected output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ |c|c| } 
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{gray!50}{1}
  \rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{}
\Body
  \hline
  \textbf{One} & \textbf{Two}\\
  \hline
  Text & More Text\\
  Even More & \makecell{Multiple \\ Lines}\\
  \hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

However, `nicematrix` has also a built-in command `\Block` which may be used here instead of `makecell`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ |c|c| } 
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{gray!50}{1}
  \rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{}
\Body
  \hline
  \textbf{One} & \textbf{Two}\\
  \hline
  Text & More Text\\
  Even More & \Block{}{Multiple \\ Lines}\\
  \hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

The output is the same.