# Fill partial tabular* row with color

Tags: tables

I am attempting to use `tabular*` to generate a table as I would like to also use the `midrule`, `bottomrule` etc. in order to get the different line thicknesses.  However, in my attempt below, as I also try to color sections of the table, I get spaces in the color like this:

[image]

I have looked at these [related solutions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435967/rowcolor-doesnt-fill-complete-cell) but wanted to know if there is a simpler solution to use here as I am still not getting my desired result.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl,tabularx}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
  \caption{Not too good looking table here.\label{tab:table1}}
  \footnotesize
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet2'
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} c|ccc}
    %\begin{tabular*}{cc|cc}
    %\toprule
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Test1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Test2}} \bigstrut[t]\\
   Test11 & Test12 & Test13 & Test14 \bigstrut[b]\\
   %\midrule
    \hline
    FLTR2 & 2     & 40    & FLTR0 \bigstrut[t]\\
    FLTR0 & 80    & 80    & FLTR0 \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .78,  .808} \textcolor[rgb]{ .612,  0,  .024}{FLTR0} & \textcolor[rgb]{ .612,  0,  .024}{160} & \textcolor[rgb]{ .612,  0,  .024}{204} & \textcolor[rgb]{ .612,  0,  .024}{FLTR4} \\
    FLTR6 & 6     & 44    & FLTR4 \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .78,  .808} \textcolor[rgb]{ .612,  0,  .024}{FLTR16} & \textcolor[rgb]{ .612,  0,  .024}{16} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}43 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}FLTR3 \\
    FLTR4 & 44    & 6     & FLTR6 \bigstrut[b]\\
    \hline
    %\bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
    %\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

How to get the color to fill the cells without any gaps and at the same time use the `toprule`, `midrule` etc?

Comment: `colortbl` really doesn't want to colour the inter-column spaces produced by `tabular*` if you really want to stretch the table, you could look at newer packages such as nicematrix or tabularray that use different mechaisms to add the coloured panels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Use of `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` insert extra spaces between columns which cannot be colored by `\rowcolor{...}`
  So, a way to use of `tabularx` is promising way, but in it you shouldn't use `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`
- At use of `tabularx` require that at least one column is type `X`
- If all columns can have the same width, than code for your table using`tabularx` can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
  \caption{Not too good looking table here.\label{tab:table1}}
  \footnotesize
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{CC|CC}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Test1}} 
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Test2}}    \\
Test11  & Test12    & Test13    & Test14                    \\
    \hline
FLTR2   & 2         & 40        & FLTR0                     \\
FLTR0   & 80        & 80        & FLTR0                     \\
\rowcolor{red!30} 
\textcolor{purple}{FLTR0} 
        & \textcolor{purple}{160} 
                    &  \textcolor{purple}{204} 
                                & \textcolor{purple}{FLTR4} \\
FLTR6   & 6         & 44        & FLTR4                     \\
\rowcolor{red!30}
\textcolor{purple}{FLTR16} 
        & \textcolor{purple}{16} 
                    & \textcolor{purple}{43¸} 
                                & \textcolor{purple}{FLTR3} \\
FLTR4   & 44        & 6         & FLTR6                     \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To my opinion this table has far to much empty spaces between columns contents. It will be nicer, if you are willing to reduce table width.

**Edit:**
An example of narrower table with colored only some cells in the first and second  column width use of `tabularray` and `siunitx` packages, MWE can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, varwidth}
\NewTableCommand\SCC[2]{\SetCell{bg=#1, fg=#2}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\caption{Not too good looking table here.}
\label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[l] Q[c, si={table-format=3.0}] |
                          Q[c, si={table-format=3.0}] Q[l] },
                 row{1} = {font=\bfseries, guard},
                 row{2} = {guard}
                 }
    \toprule
\SetCell[c=2]{c}    Test 1
        &           & \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Test 2    
                                &                   \\
Test11  & Test12    & Test13    & Test14            \\
    \midrule
FLTR2   &   2       & 40        & FLTR0             \\
FLTR0   &   80      & 80        & FLTR0             \\
\SetRow{bg=red!20, fg=purple} 
FLTR0   &   160     &   204     &   FLTR4           \\     
FLTR6   &   6       &   44      &   FLTR4           \\
\SCC{red!20}{purple}
FLTR16  & \SCC{red!20}{purple}
            16      &   43      &   FLTR3           \\
FLTR4   &   44      &   6       & FLTR6             \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your solution, however, I am running to an error, ` ! Undefined control sequence.  \l_tmpa_tl  ->\SCC{red!20}{purple} ...`

Comment: @Joe, sory, at editing of answer I forgot add definition for `\SCC`. Now corrected.

Answer (score 4):

maybe this helps--queries are welcome

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{NiceTabular}{c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} c|ccc}[colortbl-like]
        \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Test1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Test2}} \bigstrut[t]\\
        Test11 & Test12 & Test13 & Test14 \bigstrut[b]\\
        \midrule
        FLTR2 & 2     & 40    & FLTR0 \bigstrut[t]\\
        FLTR0 & 80    & 80    & FLTR0 \\
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .78,  .808} \textcolor[rgb]{ .612,  0,  .024}{FLTR0} & \textcolor[rgb]{ .612,  0,  .024}{160} & \textcolor[rgb]{ .612,  0,  .024}{204} & \textcolor[rgb]{ .612,  0,  .024}{FLTR4} \\
        FLTR6 & 6     & 44    & FLTR4 \\
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .78,  .808} \textcolor[rgb]{ .612,  0,  .024}{FLTR16} & \textcolor[rgb]{ .612,  0,  .024}{16} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}43 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}FLTR3 \\
        FLTR4 & 44    & 6     & FLTR6 \bigstrut[b]\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

To expand the table over the entire `text width`--provide `X columns` similar of the columns of `tabularx`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{NiceTabular}{c X[c]|c X[c]}[colortbl-like]
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Test1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Test2}} \bigstrut[t]\\
        Test11 & Test12 & Test13 & Test14 \bigstrut[b]\\
        \midrule
        FLTR2 & 2     & 40    & FLTR0 \bigstrut[t]\\
        FLTR0 & 80    & 80    & FLTR0 \\
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .78,  .808} \textcolor[rgb]{ .612,  0,  .024}{FLTR0} & \textcolor[rgb]{ .612,  0,  .024}{160} & \textcolor[rgb]{ .612,  0,  .024}{204} & \textcolor[rgb]{ .612,  0,  .024}{FLTR4} \\
        FLTR6 & 6     & 44    & FLTR4 \\
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .78,  .808} \textcolor[rgb]{ .612,  0,  .024}{FLTR16} & \textcolor[rgb]{ .612,  0,  .024}{16} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}43 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}FLTR3 \\
        FLTR4 & 44    & 6     & FLTR6 \bigstrut[b]\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

By replacing {tabular*} by {NiceTabular*} of `nicematrix` with the key `colortbl-like`, here is what you obtain:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
  \caption{Not too good looking table here.\label{tab:table1}}
  \footnotesize
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet2'
    \begin{NiceTabular*}{\textwidth}{c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} c|ccc}[colortbl-like]
    %\begin{tabular*}{cc|cc}
    %\toprule
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Test1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Test2}} \bigstrut[t]\\
   Test11 & Test12 & Test13 & Test14 \bigstrut[b]\\
   %\midrule
    \hline
    FLTR2 & 2     & 40    & FLTR0 \bigstrut[t]\\
    FLTR0 & 80    & 80    & FLTR0 \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .78,  .808} \textcolor[rgb]{ .612,  0,  .024}{FLTR0} & \textcolor[rgb]{ .612,  0,  .024}{160} & \textcolor[rgb]{ .612,  0,  .024}{204} & \textcolor[rgb]{ .612,  0,  .024}{FLTR4} \\
    FLTR6 & 6     & 44    & FLTR4 \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,  .78,  .808} \textcolor[rgb]{ .612,  0,  .024}{FLTR16} & \textcolor[rgb]{ .612,  0,  .024}{16} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}43 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}FLTR3 \\
    FLTR4 & 44    & 6     & FLTR6 \bigstrut[b]\\
    \hline
    %\bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular*}%
    %\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Remark that the preamble of your tabular announces 5 columns but you have used only 4.